# Play video chunks in googletv with chrome

Tags: html, video, google-tv

I am currently working on a web application for video processing. Here is the situation:

I have a mp4 h264 video as input, I split the video in multiple avi files. Each avi file is processed individually generating another avi file as an output which is immediately encoded back to h264 and is now ready to be displayed in my web application.

The problem is that in need to play those video chunks as if they were a single video but I have not been able to accomplish that in a proper way. I have tried the following solutions without having the expected results:

1. JW Player: Each time a chunk is played, the player goes black and as far as I know it is not plausible to pause it on the last frame
2. Flowplayer: Videos wont reproduce on googletv's chrome browser
3. HTML5 video tag: Behaves extrangely on googletv's chrome browser not playing the chunks completely when the `src` attribute changes and no playing at all less-than-1-second-chunks (It works fine on linux)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this on a logitech Revue or a Sony box?

Comment: You might wish to use .mp4's rather than .avi's

Comment: @Les I am using openCV to process the video and I have not been able to save other than avi files. Anyway, the files are being re-encoded again to mp4 h264 so my problem is not the encoding itself. The issue seems to be googletv's chrome browser

Comment: Have same issue on Chrome for Android... Desktop version works good but on mobile after last frame of first chnuk video got black... I think this is a chrome bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392426/html5-video-from-chunks-saved-in-indexeddb-chrome-for-android